# My "Openwith" & "Open File Location" open is disabled and appears greyed out. What can I do to restore it?

Tags: windows-10

The Openwith and Open File Location options, which appear after a right-click, seem to be disabled. The options aren't missing. They're still there but are greyed out.
I can still access the default opening option by going to properties and changing the default file setting, but that's not what I was looking for.

I found a "missing Openwith" solution but it wasn't helpful as the option isn't missing but only disabled.

Note - I use Windows 10 Home Basic

Comment: Is this for all items? And what file extensions are you trying to open?

Comment: Yes, for almost all items. I tried picture files like .jpg .png and also for other media extensions for videos and audios but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a File Association Fix online and I think it is worth giving a try.

1. Click on 'Start'
2. Type in Regedit and press enter
3. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > .Lnk`
4. In the right pane add a **String value (REG_SZ)** named **IsShortcut**

Here is a code which you can copy and paste into a text file and save as a .REG file. It will do the same as above and some more things to possibly fix the problem for you.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk]
@="lnkfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile]
@="Shortcut"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000001
"FriendlyTypeName"="@shell32.dll,-4153"
"IsShortcut"=""
"NeverShowExt"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\CLSID]
@="{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\tabsets]
"selection"=dword:00000705

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked]
"{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"=-
"{85cfccaf-2d14-42b6-80b6-f40f65d016e7}"=-

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.lnk]
```

[source](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/open-file-location-missing-right-click-shortcut-windows-7-vista/)

Comment: Sorry, this solution you gave is for a "Missing" open file location query (and that too only for shortcut files with lnk extension). But in my case, the option isn't missing. It's there and is disabled. I need a solution to enable it.

Comment: @SahayMaurya is the extension supported to open the location. I mean if the extension doesn't point to a location it canno't go to it. Or do you want to change the default program used for that extension type? Are the files on your local disk or on a cloud platform or network share?